# Inconsistent address and mask error

Tags: cisco, switch, router

When statically routing a route in the format [destination network address] [mask] [next hop address or interface name], I get the Inconsistent Address and mask error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Network address:148.148.148.48
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Hop address: 106.106.106.1

Comment: A mask of `255.255.255.0` is too large to accommodate 300 hosts.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is indicating the **host bits** of the address are not all-zero.  For a /24 network (netmask 255.255.255.0) the last byte should be zero when configuring a routing table entry.  For example: `148.148.148.0`.

Comment: I tried ip route 148.148.148.0 255.255.255.0 106.106.106.1 but my packet tracer is closing abruptly

Comment: @Noobprogrammer That's a problem with PT. The route entry is syntactically correct. The gateway needs to be locally connected, of course.